# How do I share a hash key between servers for web.config etc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, encryption

Is there a way of creating a hash key that can be used by our different servers for decrypting connection strings in web.config, and how would I do that? Any pointers?

Thanks for the help!
// Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options, if it's in-house and you want all machines to do things the same, then a machine.config syncing would be best.  You'll want a random key you generate, but here's the example element you want to change:

```
<machineKey  
validationKey="21F090935F6E49C2C797F69BBAAD8402ABD2EE0B667A8B44EA7DD4374267A75D7
               AD972A119482D15A4127461DB1DC347C1A63AE5F1CCFAACFF1B72A7F0A281B"           
decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F"
validation="SHA1"
decryption="AES"
/>
```

> To generate cryptographically random
>   keys:
>
> Use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider class
>   to generate a cryptographically strong
>   random number. Choose an appropriate
>   key size. The recommended key lengths
>   are as follows:
>
> - For SHA1, set the validationKey to 64 bytes (128 hexadecimal characters).
> - For AES, set the decryptionKey to 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters).
> - For 3DES, set the decryptionKey to 24 bytes (48 hexadecimal characters).

Since the first question I had when doing this the first time...here's an example of how to do the generation, do it once and apply to all machines: [How to create keys by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312906)

Option 2:
If you're not in that situation and you need it at the web.config level, then see [How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx) ion MSDN

Comment: Superb, but this gave me a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200329/how-do-i-know-if-the-machinekey-section-from-my-machine-config-is-being-used